# C Error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'struct pixel'

Tags: c

The signature of the set_pixel function takes a pointer to a struct pixel. So in my for loop I use the '&' sign to get the address of the struct pixel returned by get_pixel. Please I would like to understand why this doesn't work and how I can fix it.

```
struct pixel get_pixel(struct picture *pic, int x, int y);

void set_pixel(struct picture *pic, int x, int y, struct pixel *rgb);

for (int x = 0; x < get_image_width(pic->img); x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < get_image_height(pic->img); y++) {
    set_pixel(tempPic, y, get_image_width(pic->img) - x - 1,
              &get_pixel(pic, x, y));
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to store the value returned from `get_pixel()` to a variable, and then take the address of the variable. Or modify the function to return directly a pointer.

Comment: It is strangely inconsistent to me that the get is returning a value and the set is asking for a reference. Is this an API you are designing? consider either making get_pixel take an out pointer argument, or pass rgb by value to set_pixel.

Answer (score 1):

```
&get_pixel(pic, x, y)
```

The `get_pixel(pic, x, y)` returns `rvalue` and `rvalue` does not have an address, thus you can't use `&` operator on it.

What you can do is, store the return value of `get_pixel` in some temporary variable and pass the address of it to `set_pixel` function.

```
                for (int y = 0; y < get_image_height(pic->img); y++) {
                    struct pixel temp = get_pixel(pic, x, y);

                    set_pixel(tempPic,
                              y,
                              get_image_width(pic->img) - x - 1,
                              &temp);
                }
```

Note: `set_pixel` function should not store the reference of `temp` variable for further processing as its life time is within the `loop`.